# How can I run Monte-Carlo parallel using jit in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba, montecarlo

I want to parallelize a Monte-Carlo algorithm using `jit` in python. Unfortunately the normal `@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)` doesn't work, because he says their is nothing to parallelize.

The Monte-Carlo function is already working with `@jit(nopython=True)`and is called `metro3DHeiKit(config,steps,J,K,temperature)` and is a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, which takes a configuration of vectors and minimizes the energy corresponding to two values J and K.

With the following function I generate N copies of the same random configuration and want that for every temperature he calculates the Monte-Carlo configuration parallel.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit, prange
@jit(nopython=True)
def tampering(conf,Temp,steps,psteps,J,K):
    n = len(conf)
    nt = len(Temp)
    conf_copy = []


    for i in range(nt):
            conf_copy.append(np.copy(conf))

    for p in range(psteps):
        deltaE = 0 
        for i in range(nt):
            conf_copy[i] = np.copy(metro3DHeiKit(conf_copy[i],steps,J,K,Temp[i]))

    return(conf_copy)
```

The essential part that need to be parallize is:

> ```
> for p in range(psteps):
>             deltaE = 0 
>             for i in range(nt):
>                 conf_copy[i] = np.copy(metro3DHeiKit(conf_copy[i],steps,J,K,Temp[i]))
> ```

If it's needed I can provide also the Monte-Carlo function, but then I have to add also a couple of other functions which have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using `prange`?

Comment: True. I totally forgot that point. I will test it a bit and come here later to show some performance results.